# How to format an php array to desired result

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I need to display some data in the chart. Basically i have an array from database which looks like this-

```
[
    [0] =>[

            [user_type] => 'Manager'
            [total_count] => 3

        ],


    [1] =>[

            [user_type] => 'Director'
            [total_count] => 2

        ]

]
```

There is one more `user_type` which is `Trainee`  . If user `Trainee` has `0`  `Total_count` it is not coming in above array. So i need to add manually. So first will check which `user_type` is not exist in above array out of 3 user_types. If not exist then just need to add `total_count` `0`.

And finally my desired array should look like this-

```
[
    ['labels'] =>['Manager','Director','Trainee],


    ['dataset'] => [ 3, 2, 0 ]

]
```

Please notice here, Proper sequence is very important. So in above array Manager has 3, Director has 2 and Trainee has 0 total count.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First create an associative array that maps labels to counts. Then use `array_keys` and `array_values` to get the two arrays that you want in the result.

Comment: Do you have a separate user type table in your database that has all of the possible types, or is that just a text column in your user table? Is this array the result of a group by/count query?

Comment: Yes its on text base count query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code maybe It will help.

```
/*
using array column will get the result in 
Array ( [Manager] => 3 [Director] => 2 )
*/

$array_column = array_column($array, 'total_count', 'user_type');
//Create new array like below
$add_array = array('Manager'=>'0', 'Director'=>'0', 'Trainee'=>'0',);

//using array_merge merge add_array and array_column
$new_array = array_merge($add_array, $array_column);

//using array_walk_recursive get the requird result
array_walk_recursive($new_array, function($item, $key) use (&$final_array){

    $final_array['labels'][]=$key;
    $final_array['dataset'][]=$item;
    });

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_array);

?>
```

Case 1- if Trainee is not there in array 
[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/tNPfU)

Case 2 -  If Manager and  Director both are not there in array
[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/UWbkG)

Case 3- if Director is not there - [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/DLrVq)

Comment: Thanks, Shivendra! it works!

Comment: Glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script you can use with array_combine and array_map with splat(...) operator

```
$arr = array_combine(['labels','dataset'],array_map(null, ...$arr));
if(!in_array('Trainee',$arr['labels'])){
    array_push($arr['labels'],'Trainee');
    array_push($arr['dataset'],0);
}
print_r($arr);die;
```

[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

> **Note:-** In array_map NULL can be passed as a value to callback to perform a zip
>   operation on multiple arrays. If only array1 is provided, array_map()
>   will return the input array. In short to perform transpose of array operation

[Working demo](https://3v4l.org/n63Qb)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [labels] => Array
        (
            [0] => Manager
            [1] => Director
            [2] => Trainee
        )

    [dataset] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here I can see that only if trainee is not exist. But in fact it could be Manager or Director or both , then need to set their count to 0 as well. So how to achieve this?

Comment: And what if getting only one row from database? then need to add 2 user_type manually and set to 0

Comment: Please update your question concisely then

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$arr = array_combine(['labels','dataset'], array_map(null, $arr));
```

Make a function for adding non-existing user_type into array

```
function setUserType($userType, $array) {
    if(!in_array($userType, $array['labels'])){
        array_push($array['labels'], $userType);
        array_push($array['dataset'], 0);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Call function by any user_type like 'Manager', 'Trainee', 'Director'

```
$arr = setUserType('Trainee', $arr);
```

Or make an array of all user types and run a loop

```
foreach(['Manager', 'Trainee', 'Director'] as $type) {
 $arr = setData($type, $arr);   
}
```

Print and show the final value

```
print_r($arr);
die();
```

Demo https://3v4l.org/UbiXn

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$array = array();
foreach($yourArr as $row)
{
  $array['labels'][] = $row['user_type'];
  $array['dataset'][] = $row['total_count'];
}
print_r($array);
```